# select random data with a nested query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table with quite large data. Now i want to get random 4 out of it. What i need is a query that fetches 1000 records from it and then selects random 4 out of these 1000 and gives it as a result. I think it can be done by nested query but have no idea how to do it. Please help me with some example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
  select * from your_table
  where some_conditions
  limit 1000
) 
as some_aliases
order by rand()
limit 4;
```